# How to Index hstore field in Rails ? ( PG::ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR: index row size 3112 exceeds maximum 2712)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using Rails 4.0 with Postgres and I have **my_records** table like:

```
id   -> Integer 
data -> hstore
```

Please note that data field contains a long hash like:

```
{ "key1" => "val1", "key2" => "val2", .....etc }
```

Now when I try to query the table (I have around 500,000 records and big hash in data field) it's taking very long:

```
MyRecord.where("data -> 'key1' = 'val1'")
```

Now I'm trying to index **data** field using:

```
add_index :my_records, :data, using: :gin
```

But I'm getting this error when I try to run the migration:

```
PG::ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR:  index row size 3112 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "index_my_records_on_data"
: CREATE  INDEX  "index_my_records_on_data" ON "my_records" USING gin ("data")
```

Any help?

Comment: what postgres version?

Comment: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your syntax is correct - you are just exceeding the GIN index size limit.  This site describes the issue in detail and provides some alternatives:

http://sohu.io/questions/4826682/hstore-index-row-size-maximum-error

You may also want to take a step back and rethink your design.  You may be better off with a traditional NoSQL database, especially if your data is relatively dynamic.

Hope this helps.